# Mobile Service Sync Handler

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to write Azure Data Service class but I get an error like this:

The type 'MobileServiceSyncHandler' exists in both 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I couldn't find to solution but I tried to solve with .dll error of course It couldn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have both the v.1 and v.2 Azure Mobile clients installed. They implement the same stuff, but have slightly different (and incompatible) APIs. You need to uninstall the v1.3.x versions.

For more on the versions of Mobile Services vs. Mobile Apps, see [Client and server versioning in Mobile Apps and Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/).